# How to Sum Items in Generic List<T>

Tags: c#, generics

How can the following Generic List be summed up by total cost? Meaning is it possible to add both costs below to get a total?

Model:

```
public class Product
{
      public string Name {get;set;}
      public int Cost  {get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to use that model in a Generic list like this:

```
public void GetTotal()
{
     IList<Product> listOfJediProducts = new List<Product>();

     Product newProduct1 = new Product();
     newProduct1.Name = "LightSaber";
     newProduct1.Cost = 1500;
     listOfJediProducts.Add(newProduct1);

     Product newProduct2 = new Product();
     newProduct2.Name = "R2RobotSpec9";
     newProduct2.Cost = 5000;
     listOfJediProducts.Add(newProduct2);
 }
```

How would I return say a Total for Products in list?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
listOfJediProducts.Sum(p => p.Cost);
```

This runs the selector lambda expression over each element in the sequence (returning Cost in this case). The `Sum` function is then run on the "implicitly returned" IEnumerable, which obviously calculates the sum and returns it.

It is worth noting that the above is similar to writing:

```
listOfJediProducts.Select(p => p.Cost).Sum();
```

Which may be a little more obvious (if not verbose) in understanding what my first example does.

I say "implicitly returned" because Sum only makes sense on an IEnumerable of numbers, the internal workings are probably doing something closer to this:

```
int total;
foreach (Product p in listOfJediProducts)
   total += p.Cost;

return total;
```

Comment: I tried the .Sum but it doesn't show up.  Using .net 4.

Comment: What do you mean "Show up". Do you have a `using System.Linq` in your file?

Comment: Blast those Rebel Scum!!!!!!!!    I'm so used to VS alarming when that's missing....Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem, bit me more than once in the past :)

Answer (score 1):

else, using `foreach` loop

```
int total_cost = 0;
foreach (Product p in listOfJediProducts)
{
 total_cost+= p.cost;
}
```